# open instagram post iPhone hook stopped working

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

In order to open instagram app with certain post I'm using following code:

```
func instaOpen(_ postId: String, _ postUrl: String){

    let appURL = URL(string: "instagram://media?id=\(postId)")!

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(appURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        // if Instagram app is not installed, open URL inside Safari
        let webURL = URL(string: postUrl)!
        let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: webURL)
        present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When instaOpen function called – instagram app opens, but login prompt forcefully pops over. Not matter what you do - close it or proceed with login, the queried post simply won't open(see gif).
This started happening recently, after I've updated my app and pushed deployment target to iOS12.

I do have instagram listed in my `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` as well as I'm 100% positive that correct `mediaID` is being passed to `instaOpen` func (the code worked previously).

[image: issue]

Let me know if there's any suggestions on how to fix this and actually open instagram post in instagram app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated** - Facebook developer fixed the issue.

Its instagram bug you can follow its progress from https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/290173615155052/?disable_redirect=0

Comment: thanks for letting me know, i'll keep an eye on this bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bug, as that feature works on Android.

i manage to "fix" the problem on a pwa app using the Instagram web app.

```
let appURL = URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com/p/\(postId)")!
//https://www.instagram.com/p/insert here media id
```